# Angular2 to Angular4 updates error

Tags: angular

I have updated my angular2 to the current release but I got the following errors:  It seems there's an issue in the jasmine index file.

> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:37
>   A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:45
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:51
>   '=' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:45
>   A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:55
>   Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:61
>   '=' expected.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:58:41
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:99:21
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.
>
> ERROR in [default] C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:99:34
>   Cannot find name 'Partial'.

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "buy-practice-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.10",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.68",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyof` was introduced in Typescript 2.1, and in your package.json I see Typescript 2.0.3.

Unfortunately, there is a dependency on typescript 2.0.10 by @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.16, so you might not be able to upgrade to the latest typescript version (2.2.2). However, you may be able to downgrade jasmine or @types/jasmine.

I recommend that you upgrade in smaller steps. i.e. use `npm outdated` to see what version you can upgrade to based on all your dependencies. Upgrade a few libraries at a time - periodically check to make sure you haven't broken anything.  After you've upgraded what you can, next upgrade @angular to 4.0.

Comment: I have updated Typescript to 2.2.2 but I got another error.  Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined
    at applyDefaults \awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:266:72)
    at Object.ensureInstance

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my post. I suggest you update incrementally. I think that based on angular-cli, you can only upgrade to typescript@2.0.10. Start from the beginning again, and use `npm outdated`

Comment: it works now. thanks a lot!.  I have updated everything manually.